# What is diffence between the use of obj.to_i and Integer(obj) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is diffence between the use of obj.to_i and Integer(obj) in Ruby?

For example:

> a = "abc"
>
> a.to_i returns 0

but, if I use:

> Integer(a)

The return is:

> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "abc"

Why?

Comment: Because 'abc' isn't and integer and to_i returns 0 because no integer was found

Comment: Also, an error isn't a return. The integer function require an integer parameter, and to_i takes a string and parses and integer if found.

Comment: Hi, I am newbie here... and I can't find other duplicate questian...

Answer (score 4):

The difference is there in the manual:

[`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-to_i):

> If there is not a valid number at the start of `str`, `0` is returned.

[`Kernel#Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer):

> In any case, strings should be strictly conformed to numeric representation. This behavior is different from that of `String#to_i`.